# Time elapsed in calculated property from FromFileTime

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to modify the below-calculated property so it can properly calculated the time differences in seconds, minutes, hours, days if possible.

The below script is working, it's just the column **Last logon ago** still does not make sense for me.

```
$username = "Global.Admin"
Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | ForEach-Object {
    $dc = $_
    Get-ADUser $username -Properties LastLogon,DisplayName,ProxyAddresses -Server $_.Name |
        Select-Object -Property SamAccountName,
            DisplayName,
             @{n="DC"; e={$dc.Name}}, 
             @{n="IP"; e={$dc.IPv4Address}}, 
             @{n="lastLogon"; e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.'lastLogon')}},
             @{n ="Last logon ago"; e = {$((New-TimeSpan -Start ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)) -End (Get-Date)).Seconds) }},
             ProxyAddresses
} | ft -autosize
```

Comment: The ```Seconds``` property on a timespan gives the number of seconds from 0-59 - e.g. for ‘one minute and thirty seconds’ it gives ‘30’. If you want to get ‘90’ you can use ```TotalSeconds``` instead.

Comment: Small correction - ```Seconds``` can be in the range -59 to +59 - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.seconds?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks, Clayton.
Can you show me which one to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TimeSpan has built in formating functionality.

> Format Specifier Name   “c”   Constant format (not culture sensitive.
> [-]d.hh:mm:ss.[fffffff]
>
> “g”   General short format (culture sensitive)
> [-]d.hh:mm:ss.[fffffff]
>
> “G”   General long format (culture sensitive)
> [-]d.:hh:mm:ss.fffffff

E.g. This will output -00:02:13.8779620

```
$date1 = Get-Date

$date2 = Get-Date


$timespan = $date1-$date2


$timespan.ToString("c")
```

So in your case you just need to change the Seconds to .ToString("c") or what ever desired output format.

eg.

```
{$((New-TimeSpan -Start ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)) -End (Get-Date)).ToString("c")) }
```

Comment: Hi @dan, thanks for the assistance, yes it works.
So how do I remove or truncate the last digits behind the seconds?

Comment: Found it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings